# How do I replace all instances in a string using regular expressions in Progress OpenEdge

Tags: regex, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I would like to use a regular expression in OpenEdge to replace parts of a string.

In this case we want to replace SQL expressions with a symbol (now we use ?).

So what I have so far is this:

```
USING Progress.Lang.*.
USING System.Text.RegularExpressions.*.

BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

CLASS TOOLS.externals.TextSanitizer: 

    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC TextSanitizer (  ):
        SUPER ().

    END CONSTRUCTOR.

    METHOD PUBLIC CHARACTER SanitizeSql( INPUT pInputText AS CHARACTER ):

        DEFINE VARIABLE RESULT AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
        DEFINE VARIABLE regexp AS Regex NO-UNDO.

        regexp = NEW Regex("^((INSERT)\s+(INTO).*((VALUES)|(SELECT))|(SELECT).*(FROM)|(UPDATE).*(SET)|(DELETE)\s+(FROM)|((CREATE)|(DROP)|(TRUNCATE)|(ALTER)|(MODIFY))\s+((INDEX)|(TABLE)|(DATABASE)|(COLUMN)|(VIEW)))$").

        RESULT = regexp:Replace(pInputText, "?").

        DELETE OBJECT regexp.

        RETURN RESULT.

    END METHOD.

END CLASS.
```

What I have tried to get mixed casing work:

```
regexp = NEW Regex("/^rest of the regex$/ig").
```

And I wrote a procedure to run some tests:

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

USING TOOLS.externals.TextSanitizer.

DEFINE VARIABLE textSanitizer AS TextSanitizer NO-UNDO.

textSanitizer = NEW TextSanitizer().
MESSAGE textSanitizer:SanitizeSql("SELECT * FROM") VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

RETURN.
```

The tests I have run so far:

- `SELECT * FROM` --> This returns `?` as expected
- `select * from` --> This returns the original string, so mixed casing does not work, not even when I added `/i`
- `SELECT * FROM SELCT * FROM` --> This also returned `?`, while I would expect `? SELCT * FROM`
- `SELECT * FROM SELECT * FROM` --> Returns `?`, what I would expect is `? ?`

Could someone help me out here?

Comment: So you want a regex that matches *every* SQL statement? Are all targets on one line?

Comment: @Bohemian Yep, this works really nice in Python, but I can' t get it to work in OpenEdge

Answer (score 1):

First off, remove all brackets around words - they're useless noise (plus I feel like I'm back in a LISP tutorial).

If you're having trouble with case, try using the in-line flag `(?i)`.

Your quantifiers are all *greedy* instead of *reluctant*: use `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Unless all you SWL fragments occupy the whole line, you should remove the end anchor `$`.

Applying the above proposed changes, try this:

```
regexp = NEW Regex("(?i)^(INSERT\s+INTO.*?VALUES|SELECT.*?FROM|UPDATE.*?SET|DELETE\s+FROM|(CREATE|DROP|TRUNCATE|ALTER|MODIFY)\s+(INDEX|TABLE|DATABASE|COLUMN|VIEW))").
```

I have fixed the issues as asked, but won't help you with expanding the regex so it matches *every* possible SQL statement. That is too big a task.

Comment: That works for the casing, and it makes the regex a lot cleaner Awesome. However this still does require the exact match. It will not replace just a part of a string.

Comment: I just removed the ` $` from the end of the regex, and now it also processes a part of the string, but it only processes the first instance

Comment: @JohanVergeer I'm not surprised (I did ask about whole lines before). I've updated the answer regarding `$`. To match more of the command when it spills across lines, use the DOTALL flag `(?s)` (so dot matches newlines too) and the reluctant quantifier, eg `^(?is)...UPDATE.*?SET.*?WHERE`. Experiment to see what works best.

Answer (score 0):

The point here is to filter out some SQL statements because some people here think that is the best way to prevent SQL injection. (I know)

This time I solved it this way:

```
METHOD PUBLIC CHARACTER SanitizeSql( INPUT pInputText AS CHARACTER ):
    DEFINE VARIABLE regexp AS Regex     NO-UNDO.        
    regexp = NEW Regex("(?i)(INSERT\s+INTO.*?VALUES|SELECT.*?FROM|UPDATE.*?SET|DELETE\s+FROM|(CREATE|DROP|TRUNCATE|ALTER|MODIFY)\s+(INDEX|TABLE|DATABASE|COLUMN|VIEW))").

    DO WHILE regexp:IsMatch(pInputText) = TRUE:
        pInputText = regexp:Replace(pInputText, "?").
    END.

    DELETE OBJECT regexp.

    RETURN pInputText.

END METHOD.
```

First as @Bohemian suggested I added `(?i)` in front of the regex. That fixed the casing issue.
After that I removed the `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the regex string. That solved the issue with finding the beginning and end of a string.
Lastly I used `IsMatch()` in a `DO WHILE` loop to find all the instances and replace them.

Comment: I hope you are sure that SQL and not ABL injection is what you need to protect yourself from (since youre obviously run Progress ABL)...